# How can I minimize the number chars used in this Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using a sad old ERP system for reporting that is limiting the number of characters I can use when writing SQL.
I'm looking for a way to optimize the use of characters in the below select. It is ok to compromise speed here.

It's a union select:

```
   SELECT col1,col2,col3 
     FROM tabelA
    WHERE col1=colX
UNION ALL
   SELECT col1,col2,col3 
     FROM tabelB
    WHERE col1=colX
```

I tried to take the where clause out but it doesn't help much because then I need to repeat colx two times in each select and I don't like to get colX out in the report so I need to add col1,col2,col3 to the final select:

```
 SELECT col1,col2,col3 
   FROM (
            SELECT col1,col2,col3,colX
         UNION ALL
            SELECT col1,col2,col3,colX
        )
WHERE col1=colX
```

Any other ideas? It has to be a plain SELECT.

BR Kresten

Comment: Can you create a view and then select from that?

Comment: @Ted at ORCL.Pro please post your comment as the answer, this is the best idea - cerate a view, then do `SELECT * FROM x`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create a view like so:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view is
   SELECT col1,col2,col3 
     FROM tabelA
    WHERE col1=colX
UNION ALL
   SELECT col1,col2,col3 
     FROM tabelB
    WHERE col1=colX;
```

and the simply `select * from my_view`

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to create a holding(temp) table with one query and then run another simple select query to retrieve it.. or even try creating a  view . .but i assume the ERP wont take that.

Comment: ok.. i know the old systems are pain ..is there an option to shorten the column names ? so that characters are a bit less